# Seperate Lines of words and store into array

Tags: java, arrays

I have this script from a txt file which I want to store into a list of arrays

the output can only contain % and numbers:

```
jump 1500
walk 50%
jump 1280
```

I want to store them in arrays like

```
string[] arr = {"jump", "1500"};
```

and add each of the array into a list,

how do I separate each line into a array and ignore lines that doesn't follow the format in the 2nd portion (% and numbers only)

Comment: It is hard to understand what you mean by lines that doesn't follow the format. you mean if it has % you want to ignore that line? when would you ignore a line?

Comment: I think he means that the second column must be an integer or a valid %-value 0%-100%. Still....SO is not a service, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the lines into an array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// for each line ...
    // line is "jump 1500" for example
    String[] array = line.split(" ");
    list.add(array);
    // array => {"jump", "1500"}
```

To check if a String ONLY contains numbers and %, use a regex:

```
String line = "1500%";
if (line.matches("^[\\d\\%]*$") {
    // match!
}
```

The regex basically means the string start with, end with and only contains digits or %. Note that an empty string would match, if you want to enforce a min length of 1, use a + instead of *:

```
"^[\\d\\%]+$"
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try Regex to achieve this.

```
List saveList = new ArrayList();//List you want to keep result
String pattern = "[\\w]* (\\d*|\\d*%)";
String lineText = "jump 1280";//line text from your txt file
if (lineText.matches(pattern)) {
    saveList.add(lineText.split(" "));
}
```